# Recommended lemon juice to water ratio when making lemonade

Tags: drinks, ratio, lemonade

A lot of recipes I see call for lemon quantity but this can be very relative as some lemons differ in weight/size, thus yielding to different amounts of lemon juice.

For instance, if I wanted to make half a gallon's worth of lemonade, what would be the recommended ratio of lemon juice to water be? **I tend to use about 2 cups of sugar** to give you an idea of level of sweetness **in half a gallon's worth of lemonade.**

Comment: Don't lemons also differ in taste, so some are sweeter and some are more sour.

Comment: Definitely. It’s been a game of trial and error as far as brand hunting. I’ve had organic lemons that were just as sour (if not worse) than non-organic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this lemonade recipe [Best Lemonade Ever](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/32385/best-lemonade-ever/) rated by 3K people, averaging a rating of 5 stars, the ratio is

- 1 ¾ cups white sugar
- 8 cups water
- 1 ½ cups lemon juice

Since you're using 2 cups of sugar, I recommend you follow the recipe:

- 2 cups white sugar
- 9 cups water
- 1 ⅔ cups (27 tbsp) lemon juice

As for lemons to lemon juice estimate, from [How Much Juice Can You Get From One Lemon?](https://www.cookinglight.com/cooking-101/how-much-juice-in-one-lemon):

- 1 Small Lemon (4 oz.) = 3 tbsp fresh juice.
- 1 Medium Lemon (5 oz.) = 4 tbsp fresh juice.
- 1 Large Lemon (6 oz.) = 5 tbsp fresh juice

So...

- using small lemons, you'll need about 9
- using medium lemons, you'll need about 7
- using large lemons, you'll need about 5

Answer (score 1):

My mother taught me to make lemonade using a 3:1:1 ratio: 1 cup of lemon juice and 1 cup of sugar for every 3 cups of water.  Based on that ratio, if you're using 2 cups of sugar, you would also use 2 cups of lemon juice.